# VueJS how to replace dispatch with emit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to send a signal from a child component to a parent. I don't want to use Vuex as for my level of VueJS knowledge Vuex is too complicated. I am using single file components.

child.vue

```
<script>
export default {
name: 'ChildComponent',
methods: {
    // ajax post here ...
    if (response.data.status === 'accepted'){
      this.$emit('send-data', 'accepted')
    }
```

}

parent.vue

```
<script>
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue'
export default {
    name: 'Parent',
    data () {
      return {
        stage: 1
      }
    },
  components: {
      ChildComponent
  },
  // how can I replace 'events' with $on in a single file component and listen for events after all components have been created
  events: {
  'send-data': function (dataResponse) {
    if (dataResponse === 'accepted'){
      this.stage = 2
    }
  }
}
```

examples in the VueJS docs show something like this for the parent:

```
var eventHub = new Vue()
created: function () {
  eventHub.$on('add-todo', this.addTodo)
  eventHub.$on('delete-todo', this.deleteTodo)
},
```

but I want to listen to events at any time, not just on creation. How can I replace the parents 'events' with a $on function?

Comment: Attaching events on created means, the listening starts creation onwards. It doesn't limit to the creation step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start listening for event on `created` that would work for the entire life cycle of the component. Alternatively you could set event to trigger using `v-on` or `@` shortcut while using the component.

Example

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '<div><button v-on:click="sendHello">hello</button></div>',
 
 methods:{
  sendHello: function(){
   console.log('hello');
          this.$emit('hello','hello')
  }
 }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
 methods:{
  sayHi: function(){
   console.log('say hi')
  }
 }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>VueJs</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
 <my-component v-on:hello='sayHi'></my-component>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```